# Strange error on Promela - Error: syntax error saw 'keyword: do' near 'do'

Tags: spin, promela

Why is the following **Promela** code returning an error only with `N >= 34` ?

```promela
#define N 34
active proctype proc1() {

    byte i;
    select(i: 1 .. N);    //line 5

    do
        :: true ->
            printf("Hi");
        :: true -> 
            break;
    od
}
```

And the error is:

```
spin: prova.pml:5, Error: syntax error  saw 'keyword: do' near 'do'
```

I really cannot find an error. With `N <= 33` it works normally.

Is this a bug?

Comment: which version of `Spin` are you using? I cannot reproduce the issue, the error message is usually printed when there isn't any branch inside `do ... od`, but it might also be due to a missing `;`

Comment: Version 6.4.6 for macosx

Comment: Same issue if I remove the define and write the number directly in the select.

Comment: I'll test it on macos on Monday and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is (was) a bug.

Update your version of `Spin` to `6.4.7` or superior.

The [release notes](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/V6.Updates) of version `6.4.7` mention:

> - fixed a bug in the parsing of select (...) statements that could   cause unwarranted syntax errors when larger ranges are used

I could not reproduce your issue with version `6.4.8`, though it is definitively present in version `6.4.6`.